# Converting XPS Documents

Tags: c#, png, converters, xps

long time lurker first time poster here,

I'm trying to set up a XPS file handler in C# that will sit on a server, and every time a file is added or updated, the handler will take the file, convert it to an image format (most likely png), and store the image in a file to be displayed by the overall project. I'm considering using [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xps2img/), I just need to figure out how to incorporate it into the program. I'm totally open to other suggestions, so if anyone has a better idea feel free to help, or ask any more questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Using a link to a project on SourceForge does not mean that you should tag it `sourceforge`. Please use just tags that apply to the topic of your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a blog post about doing exactly that, http://craigwatson1962.com/2010/11/26/convert-an-xps-to-jpeg-png-tiff-or-bmp-in-a4-pages/ and here is a discussion regarding several ways to do it on msdn http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3ad78d46-7fa6-4697-82f9-c81d152b9a53/ if you are still having trouble ask specific questions and I will try to help.

Comment: The url should be https://craigwatson1962.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/pagination-of-xps-files-into-graphics-format-files-in-a3-or-a4-pages/